# Where/How to use a custom query in Views 3.5 D7

Tags: views, database

I have the following SQL query which produces the result I need in PHPMyAdmin and but I am lost on how I can use this query in D7.

```
SELECT sum(month.field_oct_value)
FROM uc_orders u,  field_data_group_audience ga, field_data_field_oct month
WHERE u.uid = ga.entity_id
and u.order_id = month.entity_id
and ga.bundle='user'
and ga.group_audience_gid=10
and (u.order_status='pending' OR u.order_status='payment_received' OR u.order_status='completed')
```

The query pulls integer values from field_data_field_oct for orders created by users from specific groups.  The output required is a single integer, being the sum of field_data_field_oct values retrieved.

I am looking at [views_php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) as a way of using the above, because I will be using the resulting views panes in Panels. But my php/drupal code knowledge is poor (but improving).

If anyone has any pointers on how I would use the above as the value code and an example of output code for a views_php global PHP field, I would be very grateful.

For bonus points: Ideally I would like the GID to be pulled from the viewed node's group_audience field...

Cheers,
Nick